# New concepts to use production data in non-prod environments in secured way

Tags: data-leakage

I am taking a course on information science and security at university and I am researching the best ways to secure production data in other non-production environments.

The assumption is that non-production environments are less secure and therefore production data shouldn't get to it to prevent data leakage. But in reality, it does happen for testing, developing new features etc. So therefore I studied methods to mitigate the risk as using synthetic, anonymized or masked data.

I am wondering if there are more unique and new concepts on how to use production data in non-production environments.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that non-real data or data with sensitive parts replaced is about all one can do.

Comment: I find the question still too broad. First, not all production data are sensitive. Then, how to deal with this depends a lot of what should be done with the data. It is about analyzing the data - then one needs to preserve sufficient information. It is instead about using the data to run tests - then you need to preserve at least the data needed for testing, i.e. have some transformation of the data to strip the sensitive parts but retain the test relevant parts. This could be anonymizing, could be some ML models like autoencoders ... it really depends.

Comment: Hi Ori - as it stands, this question doesn't really fit on Stack Exchange. Techniques to mitigate risk of prod data in test are either useful or not. If you are looking for current research, that's a bit open ended and will vary over time.

Answer (score 1):

Using production data in non-production environments is generally *a very bad idea*.

As you correctly stated, non-production environments are less secure. Not all the assumptions you may have about your production environment may be true about other environments.

For example, you may need to give third parties access to a staging environment to assess the security of your application (also known as penetration test). To do so, you may give them administrative access. Or, they may find a vulnerability in your system and gain access to your database. It's one thing if these third parties gain access to a staging database, another to get access to real data of your users, customers, patients, etc...

---

The way to deal with this is to use either obvious test data or [synthetic data].

#### Test Data / Mock Data

This is a data set that fulfills all technical requirements of your application, but is otherwise nonsensical. People named "Firstname Lastname",  living in "Example Road 1" on ZIP code 1234, etc.

Depending on your business needs, this may be all you need. If, for example, a developer just needs to test whether a list displays correctly when there are more than 100 users registered, then having a script that generates `user000` to `user999` is all you really need.

There are also scripts and frameworks that generate more "realistic-looking" fake data, choosing from random suitable lists. For example, here is a screenshot from [Mockaroo](https://www.mockaroo.com/), which allows you to generate mock data.

[image: Mockaroo screenshot]

You can generate datasets that mimic your schema and thus quickly fill your dev environment with data that at least fits better than "Firstname Lastname".

#### Synthetic Data

The EDPS definens synthetic data as:

> [...] artificial data that is generated from original data and a model that is trained to reproduce the characteristics and structure of the original data. This means that synthetic data and original data should deliver very similar results when undergoing the same statistical analysis.

This is generally useful if you need to train a system on data that statistically behaves in the same way as your real data, but without using actual real data. For example, anything that undergoes anomaly detection will probably need some synthetic data.

As for how to generate synthetic data is beyond the scope of this answer, but there are plenty of [scholarly articles](https://scholar.google.at/scholar?q=synthetic+data+generation) on this topic.

Comment: The OP ruled out these options and was looking for other ideas.

Comment: @schroeder None that I am aware of or have seen being used in responsible ways. "Just don't use prod data" seems the most obvious solution everyone else is using.